# Plotting the graph on the complex plain

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, complex-numbers

I would like to plot the graphic of function: `w(s) = 1/(1+s)`.

`s` is the product of the imaginary unit (`1j`) and the variable called `omega`; i.e. `s = 1j*omega`.

How I can plot that in the complex axis (Real and Imaginary) using Python (2.7 or 3.4) and `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clear in your question about what you want to plot, but assuming omega = x + iy is the number you wish to plot w(s) as a function of, you have to decide how to present the complex numbers w(s). You might choose a plot with Cartesian axes representing the real (x) and imaginary (y) axes and to plot the absolute value of w(s) as a colour, or you might choose to plot the real and imaginary parts separately.
For example,

```
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,100)
y = np.linspace(-3,0,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

def f(x, y):
    return 1./(1+1j*(x+1j*y))

import pylab
pylab.imshow(np.abs(f(X,Y)))
pylab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I am do not fully understand what do you mean, particularly why it`s necessary use a colour... If that is possible, can you solve my function please?

Comment: If `omega` is a complex number, it has a real and an imaginary part which you could represent on a two-dimensional plane. so you need to plot the values of `w(s)` in a third dimension (e.g. color the points of the plane according to its absolute value). If `omega` is real, then just plot `|w(s)|` against `omega` on a regular line-plot.